# JSP x Google Charts X MySQL: Multiple Charts Not Displaying Entire Information

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp, google-visualization

Good morning. I'm trying to make a dynamic web project in Java which connects to a MySQL database to retrieve certain information i need and display it in graphs using Google Charts. In this case, i'm trying to obtain two count values from the table post: number of posts by gender (whether Male or Female) and number of posts by location (whether East or West). Since i'm relatively new to this API, i practiced by displaying a single pie chart with the post count by gender and it works. It displays the number of posts whether the gender is male or female. However, when i try to display two charts (one pie chart with number of posts by gender and one column chart with number of posts by location), they load but they don't show the whole information. Instad of getting the number of posts for both genders and number of posts for both locations, i only get the number of posts for one gender ("Male") and the number of posts for one location ("West").

Here's a picture that illustrates what i'm trying to obtain and what i get instead: https://s31.postimg.org/40c3skgmz/output.jpg

I added some print lines in the JSP code to make sure it retrieves all the information i need and no problem there. However, that's not the case when i pass the data in the HTML.

Here's the JSP code for retrieving the data (using the JSON Library):

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>

<%
    Connection con= null;
 try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sentimentposts?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","root");

        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        ResultSet rs2 = null;

        List opdetails = new LinkedList();
        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

        String query1 = "select poster_gender, count(*) as gender_count from post group by poster_gender";
        PreparedStatement pstm1= con.prepareStatement(query1);

        String query2 = "select poster_location, count(*) as location_count from post group by poster_location";
        PreparedStatement pstm2= con.prepareStatement(query2);

           rs1 = pstm1.executeQuery();
           rs2 = pstm2.executeQuery();

           JSONObject opObj = new JSONObject();

        while (rs1.next()) {
            String gender = rs1.getString("poster_gender");
            System.out.println(gender);
            int count = rs1.getInt("gender_count");
            System.out.println(count);
            opObj.put("gender", gender);
            opObj.put("count", count);
        }

        while(rs2.next()){
            String location = rs2.getString("poster_location");
            System.out.println(location);
            int count2 = rs2.getInt("location_count");
            System.out.println(count2);
            opObj.put("location", location);
            opObj.put("count2", count2);
        }
    opdetails.add(opObj);
    responseObj.put("opdetails", opdetails);
    out.print(responseObj.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(con!= null){
            try{
            con.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 %>
```

The HTML code that displays the page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Opinion Chart Multi</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart", "bar"], callback:drawCharts});
        //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

            var queryObject="";
            var queryObjectLen="";
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getdata.jsp',
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
                    queryObjectLen = queryObject.opdetails.length;
                },
                    error : function(xhr, type) {
                    alert('server error occoured')
                }
            });

          function drawCharts() {

           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'gender');
                data.addColumn('number', 'gender_count');
                for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++)
                {
                    var gender = queryObject.opdetails[i].gender;
                    var count = queryObject.opdetails[i].count;
                    data.addRows([
                        [gender,parseInt(count)]
                    ]);
                }

           var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data2.addColumn('string', 'location');
                data2.addColumn('number', 'location_count');
                for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++)
                {
                    var location = queryObject.opdetails[i].location;
                    var count2 = queryObject.opdetails[i].count2;
                    data2.addRows([
                        [location,parseInt(count2)]
                    ]);
                }

                var options = {
                    title: 'Posts By Gender',
                };

                var options2 = {
                        title: 'Posts by Location',
                        colors: ['green','yellow'],
                        hAxis: {
                            title: 'Location'
                        },
                        vAxis: {
                            title: 'No. of Posts'
                        }
                 };

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  chart1.draw(data,options);

  var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
  chart2.draw(data2,options2);
 }        
    </script>
   </head>
  <body>

    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="chart1"></div></td>
        <td><div id="chart2"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>            

 </body>
</html>
```

And finally, the format of the SQL table i'm using:

**Table:** post

**Columns:**

message varchar(45), 
poster_age int(11), 
poster_gender varchar(45), 
poster_location varchar(45)

Answer (score 0):

most likely, `drawCharts` is being called before the data is ready...

maybe try something like this...

```
google.load("visualization", "1.0", {
  callback: function () {
    var queryObject="";
    var queryObjectLen="";
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getdata.jsp',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
        queryObjectLen = queryObject.opdetails.length;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'gender');
        data.addColumn('number', 'gender_count');
        for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++) {
          var gender = queryObject.opdetails[i].gender;
          var count = queryObject.opdetails[i].count;
          data.addRows([
            [gender,parseInt(count)]
          ]);
        }

        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn('string', 'location');
        data2.addColumn('number', 'location_count');
        for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++) {
          var location = queryObject.opdetails[i].location;
          var count2 = queryObject.opdetails[i].count2;
          data2.addRows([
            [location,parseInt(count2)]
          ]);
        }

        var options = {
          title: 'Posts By Gender',
        };

        var options2 = {
          title: 'Posts by Location',
          colors: ['green','yellow'],
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Location'
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: 'No. of Posts'
          }
        };

        var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
        chart1.draw(data,options);

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
        chart2.draw(data2,options2);
      },
      error: function (xhr, type) {
        alert('server error occoured')
      }
    });
  },
  packages:["corechart"]
});
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I applied the changes you suggested and the output remains the same... =/

Comment: can you share `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: I inserted the line "console.log(JSON.stringify(data));" immediately after "queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');" but the object doesn't get displayed in the Eclipse console like i expected. Am i missing something?

Comment: check console in browser?

Comment: I just figured out what the problem was. Apparently, it had to do with my "getdata.jsp" file: the JSONObject "opObj" should be initialized inside the result statement cycles. That's why the passed JSONObject was only storing the last line of the table. Thanks anyway! =)